# Send a file to a user, THEN load new URL using Javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, form-submit

I need to make a file available to a user, and also take them to a new URL.  The code for sending the download file is in my Submit handler.  I'm doing it like this in Chrome and Firefox:

```
function submitMyForm() {
    document.forms[0].submit();
    window.open("http://www.myURL.com");
}
```

In Chrome and Firefox, this works perfectly.  It opens myURL.com in a new tab, and prompts the user to open/save a file I created.  However, in IE9, the new tab for myURL.com is opened, but the download prompt is hidden, because it pops up at the bottom of the old, first tab, out-of-sight for user.

I tried to fix this, by sticking with only one tab like so:

```
function submitMyForm() {
    document.forms[0].submit();
    window.location.href = "http://www.myURL.com";
}
```

However, this just loads the new URL immediately, and doesn't call my submit() function, almost as if it just ignores that line entirely; this happens in all browsers, which is even worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding target = "_blank" to my form, and performing different functions based on Browser.  Thanks to [this page](http://davidwalsh.name/detecting-google-chrome-javascript) for helping to detect Chrome.

```
function submitform() {
    document.forms[0].submit();

    //Test for Chrome
    if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1) {
        //this works in Chrome
        window.open("http://www.myURL.com");
    }
    else {
        //this works in IE9 and Firefox
        window.location.href = "http://www.myURL.com";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once a form is submitted all action on the current page stops, unless you're posting to a new page (target="") or iframe.

Comment: That's not what's happening.  The "document.forms[0].submit()" line is being ignored, and the "window.location.href" line is being called.